# Wix toolset - Bundle MSI Install Conditions - Not Silent Install

Tags: wix

I am trying to achieve something that on the surface is simple. From my bundle, I need to install an MSI package based on a few conditions. Both of these conditions work fine independently however when added together it doesn't work.

Conditions.
Install if Dulx or Basic and if NOT in silent mode.

```
<MsiPackage
        Id="Prep"
        Compressed="yes"
        Name="Redist\InstallCheckList.msi"
        SourceFile="$(var.InstallCheckList.TargetDir)Prep.msi"
        DisplayInternalUI="no"
        Vital="yes" 
        InstallCondition="(InstallTypeDulx=1 OR InstallTypeBasic=1) AND UILEVEL > 2" >
        <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLLOCATION" Value="[InstallFolder]" />
    </MsiPackage>
```

I have tried surrounding the InstallTypes and UIlevel in (), i've tried replacing the > then with >.
Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probable mean `WixBundleUILevel`: https://wixtoolset.org/docs/tools/burn/builtin-variables/

Comment: Ah thanks. I'll give it a go. Is this value also available within a custom action? Also from my understanding this is only in 3.11? I don't believe we are on that 3.10 I think.

Comment: WixBundleUILevel is a bundle variable, so it's not available in a custom action unless you pass it in as an MsiProperty.

Comment: That got it! Thanks. had to update to Wix 3.11 as per docs. Thanks again.

Comment: Would you mind giving me an example? I know how to pass in a MSI for example
<MsiProperty Name="UserIULang" Value="[UserUILanguageID]" />

I am trying to get this Burn value in my Custom action. I have tried setting a variable in the MSI to equal this but its not found in the session, or is called "UserUILanguageID" as a string an not the value.

Thanks for you help so far. Been really helpful!

Comment: `MsiProperty` is how you do it and `[BurnVariable]` is how you reference the variable. The log will show what's passed to MSI.